# Why is drawing to a hidden HDC giving different results than when drawing to the HDC returned by GetDC(HWND)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, gdi+, win32gui

I have two methods, paintDoubleBuffered and paint. They are both supposed to draw this image on the screen:
[image: An map of a lake]

The image is made up of approximately 12 smaller images each sized 256x256 tiled together.

My standard painting method works as expected. Here it is:

```cpp
void MainWindow::paint(HWND hwnd) {

    HDC hdc{GetDC(hwnd)};
    paint(hwnd, hdc);
    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);

}

void MainWindow::paint(HWND hwnd, HDC hdc) {
    constexpr INT img_width{ MDNR_Map::pannel_width };
    constexpr INT img_height{ MDNR_Map::pannel_height };

    const INT width{ GetDeviceCaps(hdc, HORZRES) };
    const INT height{ GetDeviceCaps(hdc, VERTRES) };

    const INT num_width_pannels{ (width / img_width) + 1 };
    const INT num_height_pannels{ (height / img_height) + 1 };

    Gdiplus::Graphics g(hdc);

    g.SetCompositingMode(CompositingMode::CompositingModeSourceCopy);

    g.SetInterpolationMode(InterpolationMode::InterpolationModeNearestNeighbor);

    for (INT y = 0; y < num_height_pannels; y++) {
        for (INT x = 0; x < num_width_pannels; x++) {

            Location_t get_loaction(x + map_location.x, y + map_location.y, map_location.layer);
            const IMG_t v{ mdnr_map.get(get_loaction) };

            const Point drawPoint((INT)(img_width * x), (INT)(img_height * y));

            Status stat{ g.DrawImage(v, drawPoint) };

            if (stat != Status::Ok)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error(":(");
            }


        }
    }
}
```

The issue with that paint method is that mdnr_map.get is an io bound call and may take several micro seconds. Because I need to call it about 12 times, it can lead to flickering.

To solve this, I attempted to write a double-buffered paint method, which is as follows:

```cpp
void MainWindow::paintDoubleBuffered(HWND hwnd) {

    // Get DC for window
    HDC hdc{ GetDC(hwnd) };

    const INT win_width{ GetDeviceCaps(hdc, HORZRES) };
    const INT win_height{ GetDeviceCaps(hdc, VERTRES) };

    // Create an off-screen DC for double-buffering
    HDC hdcMem{ CreateCompatibleDC(hdc) };

    HBITMAP hbmMem{ CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, win_width, win_height) };

    HANDLE hOld{ SelectObject(hdcMem, hbmMem) };

    // Draw into hdcMem here
    paint(hwnd, hdcMem);

    // Transfer the off-screen DC to the screen
    BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, win_width, win_height, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    // Free-up the off-screen DC
    SelectObject(hdcMem, hOld);

    DeleteObject(hbmMem);
    DeleteDC(hdcMem);
}
```

However, this does not work and instead produces this abombination of an image:
[image: A distorted map of a lake]

With a little poking and proding, I was able to discover that if I changed my double buffered paint method by multiplying the image size by 1.5, the image was no longer so garbled, but was now zoomed in by a factor of 1.5

```cpp
void MainWindow::paintDoubleBuffered(HWND hwnd) {

    // Get DC for window
    HDC hdc{ GetDC(hwnd) };

    const INT win_width{ GetDeviceCaps(hdc, HORZRES) };
    const INT win_height{ GetDeviceCaps(hdc, VERTRES) };

    // Create an off-screen DC for double-buffering
    HDC hdcMem{ CreateCompatibleDC(hdc) };

    HBITMAP hbmMem{ CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, win_width, win_height) };

    HANDLE hOld{ SelectObject(hdcMem, hbmMem) };

    // Draw into hdcMem here
    
    constexpr INT img_width{ MDNR_Map::pannel_width + 128 }; // MDNR_Map::pannel_width is 256
    constexpr INT img_height{ MDNR_Map::pannel_height + 128}; // MDNR_Map::pannel_height is 256

    const INT num_width_pannels{ (win_width / img_width) + 1 };
    const INT num_height_pannels{ (win_height / img_height) + 1 };

    Gdiplus::Graphics g(hdcMem);

    g.SetCompositingMode(CompositingMode::CompositingModeSourceCopy);

    g.SetInterpolationMode(InterpolationMode::InterpolationModeNearestNeighbor);

    for (INT y = 0; y < num_height_pannels; y++) {
        for (INT x = 0; x < num_width_pannels; x++) {

            Location_t get_loaction(x + map_location.x, y + map_location.y, map_location.layer);
            Gdiplus::Bitmap* pannel{ mdnr_map.get(get_loaction) };

            const Point drawPoint((INT)(img_width * x), (INT)(img_height * y));

            Status stat{ g.DrawImage(pannel, drawPoint) };
            if (stat != Status::Ok)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error(":(");
            }

        }
    }

    // Transfer the off-screen DC to the screen
    BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, win_width, win_height, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    // Free-up the off-screen DC
    SelectObject(hdcMem, hOld);

    DeleteObject(hbmMem);
    DeleteDC(hdcMem);
}
```

[image: Zoomed in map image]

**My question is why does drawing to the HDC returned by CreateCompatibleBitmap produce a different result than drawing to the HDC returned by GetDC?**

**I have tried:**
All raster-operation codes for BltBlt.
I have checked that the temporary HDC is the same size as the window.
I have tried replacing the code snippet

```
const INT win_width{ GetDeviceCaps(hdc, HORZRES) };
const INT win_height{ GetDeviceCaps(hdc, VERTRES) };
```

with

```
RECT rect;
GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rect);

const INT win_width{ rect.right - rect.left };
const INT win_height{ rect.bottom - rect.top };
```

**I have also called SetProcessDPIAware() before drawing.**

Upon feedback from @Paul Sanders, I rewrote my paintDoubleBuffered method as follows, NOTE, I have called BufferedPaintInit in the object constructor:

```
void MainWindow::paintDoubleBuffered(HWND hwnd) {

    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc{ BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps)};

    RECT sz;
    GetWindowRect(hwnd, &sz);

    BP_PAINTPARAMS paintParams = { 0 };

    paintParams.cbSize = sizeof(paintParams);
    paintParams.dwFlags = BPPF_ERASE;
    paintParams.pBlendFunction = NULL;
    paintParams.prcExclude = NULL;

    HDC hdcBuffer;

    HPAINTBUFFER hBufferedPaint = BeginBufferedPaint(hdc, &sz, BPBF_COMPATIBLEBITMAP, &paintParams, &hdcBuffer);

    if (hBufferedPaint && this->bufferedInitResult == Ok) {
        // Application specific painting code
        paint(hwnd, hdcBuffer);
        EndBufferedPaint(hBufferedPaint, TRUE);
    }
    else{
        paint(hwnd, hdc);
    }

    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
}
```

Unfortunately, this did not work and the resultant screen looks like this:
[image: A messed up map with a white boarder to the top and left]

Comment: I'm not sure what `const INT win_width{ GetDeviceCaps(hdc, HORZRES) };` and `const INT win_height{ GetDeviceCaps(hdc, VERTRES) };` are supposed to be doing, but the likely fix is to use `GetClientRect (hwnd)` here instead.

Comment: The GetDeviceCaps function retrieves device-specific information for the specified device. Passing HORZRES makes it return the width, in pixels, of the screen; or for printers, the width, in pixels, of the printable area of the page. Passing VERTRES makes it return height, in raster lines, of the screen; or for printers, the height, in pixels, of the printable area of the page. More documentation can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getdevicecaps

Comment: I am looking at this piece of code: ```constexpr INT img_width{ MDNR_Map::pannel_width + 128 };...```  and ```constexpr INT img_height{ MDNR_Map::pannel_height + 128}; ...```. As you say, image is 256x256. So it is exactly that you do, you increase heigth and width by 0.5, from 256x256 to (256+128)x(256+128), it is your factor of 1.5.

Comment: Yes, that is how I figured out that there is scaling going on. What it does not tell me is where the scaling is coming from. Why does it scale?

Comment: @Joser_V Yes, I know that.  Question is, why do you think that is relevant to your use case.  I have never needed to bother with any of that to do (successfully) what you are trying to do.  Check out also Windows' built in (`BeginBufferedPaint`)[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uxtheme/nf-uxtheme-beginbufferedpaint] function (don't forget to read the notes at the foot of that page).

Comment: 1.  You don't want the dimensions of the screen, but the dimensions of your window.   2. If your application isn't manifested for HiDPI support, Windows will lie to you about the screen resolution, your window size, and so in.

Comment: I have a very strong suspicion that if you search Windows Control Panel for "Make everything bigger" you will see a scaling factor of 150% there.  That's the factor by which Windows lies.  If you manifest your application as HiDPI-aware, the lies will stop.

Comment: https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/05/19/improving-high-dpi-experience-gdi-based-desktop-apps/

Comment: @PaulSanders I took a look at the links you posted and thought they looked quite promising. Unfortunately, my implementation of buffered drawing using BeginBufferedPaint seems to have failed. If you have any other suggestions or see that I have written something stupidly, I would be happy to hear it.

Comment: Why would you call GetWindowRect when you were told to use GetClientRect?

Comment: @Joser_V It scales because it is exactly that you do in your program, you use that scaled widgh/heigth ```drawPoint((INT)(img_width * x), (INT)(img_height * y))```  to scale

Comment: There looks to be quite a lot wrong, but please don't move the goalposts like this.  Instead, please roll your edit back, and, if you're planning on sticking with `BeginBufferedPaint`, ask a new question. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being not in the approach to double buffering, but in the call to `Graphics::DrawImage(Image*, Gdiplus::Point)` in my paint method. Changing to `DrawImage(Image* image, INT x, INT y, INT width, INT height)` fixed the scaling issue.

Comment: Also, changing from GetWindowRect to GetClientRect fixed the white space issue.